# Manually created scilab launcher doesn't work

Tags: shortcuts

I try to create shortcuts when an application are running thanks to the icon that appear on the left side and I do `Lock to launcher` (which actually impede to take a screen shot). Yet, I did it for Eclipse and even if there is an icon, it doesn't work and for SciLab it would never work.

Therefore, how to create shortcuts for programs on Ubuntu?

I created a file `SciLab.desktop` as suggested by Nitesh Sharma

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=./bin/scilab
Name=SciLab
Comment=comment here
Icon=/home/antoine/scilab-5.5.2/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/scilab.png
```

and then did `chmodx ScilLab.desktop` but I have then an error and I am not able to stick it to the menu on the left.

[image]

But I don't know what to do from there.

Comment: How did you install scilab? It is in the repos.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I did it with `tar xzvf scilab-5.5.2.bin.linux-x86_64.tar.gz # For 64 bits systems` then to launch it I did `cd Downloads/scilab-5.5.2` and `./bin/scilab`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The downloaded version has a number of `.desktop` files in `.../scilab-5.5.2/share/applications`

These `.desktop` files however assume the application is in `$PATH`, since the commands in the files to not include an absolute path to the binaries. 
There is also an instruction on which commands to run when, in `.../scilab-5.5.2/share/applications`.

I would however save yourself the time, and install `scilab` simply from the repos (not from the downloaded file) by the command:

```
sudo apt-get install scilab
```

The version in the repos seems to be pretty much up-to-date!

#### Note

in case you might have saved one or more `scilab` "home-made" `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications`, be sure to remove them, since they will overrule the global ones, installed from `apt-get`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did the command but I don't know how to launch it know

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

Note: I'm using Scilab v6.0 on CentOS 7 running Gnome 3 Desktop.

1. Open a terminal
2. Goto Desktop directory (/home/$yourname/Desktop/)
3. Create a scilab desktop file (touch scilab.desktop)
4. Open the file and add the following content to the file (vi scilab.desktop) 
   Note: the Exec=path to your scilab executable and Icon=path to your scilab icon

[Desktop Entry]

Version=1.0

Type=Application

Terminal=true

Exec=/home/$YOURNAME/apps/scilab-6.0.0/bin/scilab

Name=scilab

Comment=

Icon=/home/$YOURNAME/apps/scilab-6.0.0/share/icons/hicolor/32x3/apps/scilab.png

Comment[en_US.utf8]=

Name[en_US]=Scilab 6.0

5. Change file permission to 755 (chmod 755 scilab.desktop)